# Regex domain with php

Tags: php, regex

I get html source include these domains (not http://)

ex:

```
<table>
<tr><td>abc.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc.net</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc.com.vn</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc.vn</td></tr>
</table>
```

how I have to do with Regular Expresion export domains ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this to extract your domains..

```
<?php
$content ="<table>
<tr><td>abc.com</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc.net</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc.com.vn</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc.vn</td></tr>
</table>";
preg_match_all('/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc.com
    [1] => abc.net
    [2] => abc.com.vn
    [3] => abc.vn
)
```